# Count number of repeated in the list

Tags: python-2.7

Hey Guys I'mm not good in Python....need help!

I have a file which contain the following list (IP addresses),

```
10.2.1.12    
192.12.23.2    
10.2.1.12     
192.11.23.1   
10.2.1.12     
192.12.23.2
```

Expected Output:

```
IP Address              count( number of repeated )
10.2.1.12                       3
192.12.23.2                     2              
192.11.23.1                     1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects):

```
from collections import Counter

with open('ip.txt') as f:
    cnt = Counter(line.strip() for line in f)
    print('{:<20} {}'.format('IP Address', 'count(number of repeated)'))
    for ip, c in cnt.most_common():
        print('{:<20} {}'.format(ip, c))
```